# Edit and checkin versions.txt file in GitHub Actions using powershell

Tags: github-actions, github-for-windows

I see the documentation in github actions to run a powershell script in a step. I need to increment version number and checkin versions.txt file in GitHub Actions using powershell. Can I accomplish this by running a powershell script from my folder and by using git.exe and powershell commands?

How do I set a variable from powershell script to use the version number in subsequent steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two questions in your question, I will answer in reverse order.

To have one step (for example shell script) set a value for subsequent steps, you can use the special workflow commands which are just done by outputting specially formatted strings to STDOUT.

In your case, are looking for [Setting an Output Parameter](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter):

```
echo "::set-output name=version::1.2.3"
```

Which can then be read by subsequent steps, like this (for example):

```
env:
  VERSION: ${{ steps.the-other-step-id.outputs.version }}
```

As for having GitHub actions modify code and then check it in, I would strongly advise against it as it will a) complicate your workflow, b) might create "workflow loops", where actions-originated checkins trigger this/other workflows.

For version tagging, I suggest you use tags as it is the almost universally accepted way to mark versions in source control. You might want to have a local script that both tags and updates your version.txt, and then your workflow just reads the file or the tag.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use the output parameter. But regarding updating version.txt in a step, I'm also generating version number of .net assembly & executable plus package version in the build. Without using a step in GitHub action, is it possible to increment version.txt? I want version.txt towards the end of the build, that is only if it was successful.

Comment: This helped to solve pushing version.txt: https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action